# Using Dynamic instead of reflection to call method by name

Tags: c#, reflection, dynamic, .net-4.0, methods

Using .NET-4.0, how would I use Dynamic to accomplish the following without using reflection?

```
     public void InvokeMethod(string methodName)
    {
        Type t = typeof(GCS_WebService);
        GCS_WebService reflectOb = new GCS_WebService();
        MethodInfo m = t.GetMethod(methodName);
        m.Invoke(reflectOb, null);
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dynamic typing in C# doesn't provide for that - the names of the members you want to access still has to be known at compile-time. (You could create the call site yourself of course and use the rest of the machinery of the DLR to resolve things, but it wouldn't be any simpler than using reflection, and it wouldn't really be using the *language* features.)

Comment: It wouldn't be simpler, but it could be *faster* (assuming it can take advantage of the call site caching).

Comment: Thanks!  I seen other threads here mentioning it could be done, but without examples.  Now I know why there were no examples.

Answer (score 5):

The open source framework [Impromptu-Interface](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/) has methods the automate all the plumbing to use the DLR to resolve [really late](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/wiki/UsageReallyLateBinding) like this. It runs 70% faster than reflection with void returning methods.

```
  public void InvokeMethod(string methodName)
    {
        var reflectOb = new GCS_WebService();
        Impromptu.InvokeMemberAction(reflectOb, methodName)
    }
```