# Why not use `dynamic` instead of reflection when the property is known?

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection

This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358224/using-dynamic-instead-of-reflection-to-call-method-by-name), but assuming that we know the member name at compile time.

---

Assuming that we have a class

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string TheProperty { get; set; }
}
```

and in another method, we want to set the `TheProperty` member of an instance of that class, but we don't know the type of the instance at compile time, we only know the property name at compile time.
So, as I see it, there are two ways to do that now:

```
object o = new MyClass(); // For simplicity.

o.GetType().GetProperty("TheProperty").SetValue(o, "bar"); // (1)    
((dynamic) o).TheProperty = "bar"; // (2)
```

I measured this test case using the `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` class to find out that **reflection took 475 ticks** and the way using **`dynamic` took 0 ticks**, therefore being about as fast as a direct call to `new MyClass().TheProperty = "bar"`.

---

Since I have almost never seen the second way, I am a little confused and my questions now are:

- **Is there a lapse of thought or anything?**
- **Should the second way be preferred over the first or the other way around?** I don't see any disadvantages of using the second way; both (1) and (2) would throw exceptions if the property would not have been found, wouldn't they?
- **Why does the second way seem to be used so rarely even though seemingly being the faster?**

Comment: The main purpose of `dynamic` is for _anonymous types_ in LINQ or as a simpler way for talking to COM without all the tedius mucking about in hyperspace, erm I mean type libraries and such.  So otherwise yes, you probably would not use it much.  Also, `dynamic` should be used with care as even though it may compile, you might get a runtime error if the member was not found (much like reflection).  Except for the case of anonymous types of course

Comment: Yes, you're right, and I also considered runtime errors, but I figured that  both cases (as you already said) would lead to a runtime error, so I don't think this is the sole reason the use of `dynamic` in this case is seemingly discouraged.

Comment: Generally yes.  It is quite awesome for anonymous types in LINQ in the same way anonymous methods and lambda expressions are

Comment: There is no way to check if "TheProperty" actually exists first before you use it AFAIK but you could with reflection. Depends on your use case I guess.

Comment: @pmcilreavy you're right, that is something I did not yet take into consideration.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and don't hand-roll microbenchmarks; there are a lot of things you have to take into consideration for your benchmark to become representative this way. Use someone else's hard work: http://benchmarkdotnet.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> (...)reflection took 475 ticks and the way using dynamic took 0 ticks(...)

That is simply false. The problem is that you are not understanding how `dynamic` works. I will assume you are correctly setting up the benchmark:

1. Running in Release mode with optimizations turned on and without the debugger.
2. You are jitting the methods before actually measuring times.

And here comes the key part you are probably not doing:

3. Jit the dynamic test *without actually performing the dynamic runtime binding*.

And why is 3 important? Because the runtime will *cache* the dynamic call and reuse it! So in a naive benchmark implementation, if you are doing things right, you will incurr the cost of the initial dynamic call jitting the method and therefore you won't measure it.

Run the following benchmark:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var repetitions = 1;
    var isWarmup = true;
    var foo = new Foo();

    //warmup
    SetPropertyWithDynamic(foo, isWarmup); //JIT method without caching the dynamic call
    SetPropertyWithReflection(foo); //JIT method
    var s = ((dynamic)"Hello").Substring(0, 2); //Start up the runtime compiler

    for (var test = 0; test < 10; test++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Test #{test}");
        var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        for (var i = 0; i < repetitions; i++)
        {
            SetPropertyWithDynamic(foo);
        }

        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"Dynamic benchmark: {watch.ElapsedTicks}");

        watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        for (var i = 0; i < repetitions; i++)
        {
            SetPropertyWithReflection(foo);
        }

        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"Reflection benchmark: {watch.ElapsedTicks}");
    }

    Console.WriteLine(foo);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void SetPropertyWithDynamic(object o, bool isWarmup = false)
{
    if (isWarmup)
        return;

    ((dynamic)o).TheProperty = 1;
}

static void SetPropertyWithReflection(object o)
{
    o.GetType().GetProperty("TheProperty").SetValue(o, 1);
}

public class Foo
{
    public int TheProperty { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() => $"Foo: {TheProperty}";
}
```

Spot the difference between the first run and the subsequent ones?

Comment: thanks for your efforts. I tried it your way and I must say I am shocked how slow `dynamic` is compared to reflection - which answers the question and explains why I have only ever seen reflection and not `dynamic`. Thank you very much.

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow You are welcome. One small commentary; I've updated the answer to remove the cost of starting up the compiler at runtime. It improves the dynamic call somewhat but it *is* a cost that you will incurr on the first dynamic call (you wont on all subsequent ones, cached or not).

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow Well don't be too hard on `dynamic`.  Don't forget reflection is considerably slower than just doing a straight-up `myClass.TheProperty = "Up..up..and away!"`.  There's even a difference (though small) between calling directly and say delegates or via interface. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973852.aspx :)

Comment: @InBetween thank you for pointing out all the JIT / compiler costs, and thanks for the code & comments.

Comment: @MickyD I'm not being too hard on `dynamic`, I was just very surprised to see my "benchmark" being so wrong and showing completely absurd results... :D